# Floating span within ol li appears correct in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to display a list of items each with two spans side by side and evenly spaced.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<ol id="peerTimes">
   <li id="142_177_85_207__60212">
      <span class="ip">142.177.85.207</span>
      <span class="dateTime time">Tuesday, December 04, 2012 8:34:21 PM</span>
   </li>
   <li id="127_0_0_1__52375">
      <span class="ip">127.0.0.1</span>
      <span class="dateTime time">Tuesday, December 04, 2012 8:34:09 PM</span>
   </li>
</ol>
```

And the CSS looks like this:

```
.ip {
    float: left;
    width: 170px; 
}
.dateTime {
    width: auto;  
}
```

In Firefox, this looks how I want it to:
[image]

But in Chrome, no matter how much I mess with it, the list item number always gets pushed to after the floating span:
[image]

Is there cross-browser friendly way to achieve this layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just change your CSS to:

```
.ip {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 170px; 
}
```